# Error printing crystal report in my c# app

Tags: log4net

I made a c# program with VS 2019 with crystal report for visual studio.  All works well in my machine.

I'm installing in my client with Clickonce.  But I having a problem in my client with this error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception. ---> 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException:
 Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. 
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils.get_CurrentControl()
   at CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils.GetEffectiveCulture()
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.CREngineRes.GetString(String name)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.CheckForCrystalReportsRuntime()
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..ctor()
   at PatientTrackingSystem.MainWindow.<PrintReportAsync>d__143.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at PatientTrackingSystem.MainWindow.<cmdPrintRouteSlip_Click>d__144.MoveNext()
```

For the file log4net, I changed the publish Status in the Application Files  to "Include" but I still have the same error.

Then I installed  the log4net NuGet Package in my application, remade the clickonce setup, and I still have the same error.

When I look in the my client machine, I see that file where clickonce install the application.

Any idea to fix that issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are facing issue while loading the file which used to append your logs, please mention the steps you have followed and make sure your config file and assembly file is correct, most of the issue is due to your config file .

1. You have to go to AssemblyInfo.cs and include

   [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
2. You have to make sure in your config file file path under this tag is correct :